# Wss4jSecurityInterceptor on Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

Eclipse is complaining that it cannot find Wss4jSecurityInterceptor when I'm trying to wire it up in my Spring Boot configuration (it's not available for importing):

```
@Bean public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor(){...}
```

Here's the relevant extract from the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc-connectivity-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>abc-connectivity-boot</name>
    <description>FFM Connectivity via Digested UserNameToken</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.
Simeon

With **spring-ws-security** dependency added to the pom.xml (as per M. Deinum's suggestion) I'm now seeing the following run time error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/security/WSSecurityException
    at connect.ConnectivityTestingConfig.wss4jSecurityInterceptor(ConnectivityTestingConfig.java:68)
    at connect.ConnectivityTestingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e29e9046.CGLIB$wss4jSecurityInterceptor$4(<generated>)
    at connect.ConnectivityTestingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e29e9046$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$bb38be14.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at connect.ConnectivityTestingConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e29e9046.wss4jSecurityInterceptor(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
```

Adding the following dependency:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
```

seem to resolve the above error, but is this a move in the right direction?
Concerns:

1. With the above additions, should **spring-boot-starter-security** be present in the pom.xml?
2. How does one control the versions of the added **wss4j** and should one?  For example, wss4j-1.5.8.jar seems to be incompatible, while wss4j-1.6.18 seems to work.  How does one correlate the version of Spring Boot to its required dependencies?

Could someone please comment on the approach?  Here's the resulting pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.18</version>
        <!-- <type>jar</type> -->
        <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I checked the spring-ws-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar which seems to be associated with the above version on Spring Boot and see that it doesn't contain 'security' package in which Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java is supposed to reside, whereas it is present in the Spring Boot sources (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/tree/2.2.1.RELEASE/spring-ws-security/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/wss4j).  Could someone please shed some light on this for me?

Comment: No it isn't it is in the `spring-ws-security` jar which you need to add.

Comment: Please don't add code, xml, stack traces as comments, improve your original question with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with this working configuration:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <audit-lib.version>1.0.0</audit-lib.version>
        <cxf.version>3.1.0</cxf.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-test</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version> -->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fuwt.iws</groupId>
            <artifactId>audit-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${audit-lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->       



    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact I had the same problem and this answer helped me. When using Maven to add the dependency to wss4j you have the choice to add a bundle or zip/source reference, resulting in a dependency like the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.19</version>
        <type>zip</type>
        <classifier>source-release</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

This resulted in a NoClassDefFoundError. I got it to work by removing the type and classifier elements like mentioned in the answer above:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

After this correction my code worked fine. BTW I had no need to add any of the other dependencies following this one in the answer above.